# Firebase + Express cannot GET any route except '/'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase

I am unable to process GET or POST to any destination other than the root '/'. The output is just a 404 error with "Cannot GET /hello" if I try to access that path. Below is the simplest example I can conceive of but it still fails. I have experimented with using routers and app.use but get the same error.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const engines = require('consolidate');

const app = express();
app.engine('hbs', engines.handlebars);
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("This works");
    res.render(mytemplate, {});
});

app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    console.log("This is never logged");
    res.render(mytemplate, {}); //never happens
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```